# How can I access the list of items on the Queue in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

**The Setup**

I'm using [Laravel 5.1](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1) to build an application that processes a large number of media files.  To handle the processing I've decided to use the built in [queue services](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues) for some of the more labor intensive pieces of the process.  I'm using the database driver.

**The Need**

I would like to create a dashboard so that non-technical administrators can know what processes are being run, and generally monitor the activity of the system.  This means I would like to show them failed jobs, queued jobs, and in progress jobs.

Specifically I have the following questions:

1. How do I get a list of pending items in the Laravel queue?
2. How do I get a list of failed items in the Laravel queue?

Also I imagine I'm not the first to want a UI around the queue, so: anything already out there I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interesting in this still, please use Laravel Horizon. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/horizon

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a service like [Iron](https://www.iron.io).

I also found something here: [phpBeanstalkdAdmin](http://mnapoli.fr/phpBeanstalkdAdmin/). You may also use this.